# Multiple mpirun executions at the same time?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, mpi, cpu

I have a list of mpirun commands serially in a bash script. I can run the bash script that causes the individual mpirun commands to be executed serially (but parallel within themselves). Now, each of these mpirun commands require only a fraction of total computational resources the system has. That means, when the first mpirun command executes, only few CPUs are working, rest should be idle. Is there a way to again 'channelize' each mpirun commands of the bash script into different sets of CPUs so that almost all the computing resources get used efficiently? (Extra: Each mpirun command executes a common python code but with different set of arguments.)

Comment: You are looking for a Resource Manager such as SLURM. Extra: look at job arrays

Comment: Question unclear. When you say "only. few CPUs" are working, are you referring to few cores of a node, or few nodes of a cluster? How big is your system?

Comment: Single machine: 30 cores. Say total 10 mpirun commands, each should be using 3 cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to use a scheduler like slurm, you can control which resources are allocated to each mpirun application and launch several instances taking a subpart of the node(s) resources. This is sometimes referred to as "sub-scheduling", see for instance [this example](https://docs.lxp.lu/first-steps/handling_jobs/#sub-scheduling)